# Better way to handle RESTful services in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm developing a large JavaScript application and using .NET as the backend is a requirement.  I've had to really fight WCF to give me good JSON URLs, error messages, etc and wanted to see if there was a better framework out there in .NET for things like that.  I'm wishing there was a similar approach like NodeJS's Express framework has for services.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely checkout [`ASP.NET Web API`](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and [`ServiceStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/) if you intend to develop RESTful services in .NET. Personally I use ServiceStack and it is a really nice framework for developing REST services.

Comment: Asp.Net WebAPI is the "new and improved" WCF.  Especially of a RESTFUL flavor.  I agree, WCF/JSON was tough to figure out.

Comment: What about push notifications and things like that?  Is there anything like socketio for .net yet?

Comment: @amcdnl, for push notifications there's SignalR.